# how to insert data into MySql using Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, the Copy activity doesn't support MySQL table in Sink setting ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview)). I need to copy some data from another database's table into a relevant MySQL table. Do we have any other Activity that can do the MySQL's insertion? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guide to using an ODBC sink/source

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory

- Install a self hosted runtime on a server
- Connect the self hosted runtime to the ADF instance
- Install the MySQL ODBC driver on the server, set up a DSN and test it
- Test it in the self hosted runtime console
- Set up an ODBC linked service in ADF. Test it

Comment: I have to insert some data into a table in an Amazon's Aurora - MySQL serverless instance. So, I created a basic Windows 2012  data center server (30GB SSD-4GB RAM), installed odbc driver for mysql, and install a self-hosted runtime integration in the same Virtual Private Cloud on Amazon. After changing some Firewall rules to allow this server connect to the MySQL DB, port 3306, I was able to follow your instructions. Thanks a lot.